# Adding a message box with Ok button inside an onCLickListener()

Tags: android, messagebox, android-applicationinfo

I am trying to add an `Ok button` by following a post and tried that code but somehow it shows me an error

`Builder (android.content.Context) in builder cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.onClickListener)`

Here is my code

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Arrays.asList(input).contains("")){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setMessage("You still have unanswered questions. Please go back");
                alert.setTitle("Notice");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                            }
                        });
            }else {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),gcfResult.class);
                startActivity(in);


            }
        }
    });
```

The error is on `this` keyword at below line

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: this references to View.onClickListener you probably using this code in activity lets say MyActivity you should create builder like this"new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityname.this);
```

because `new View.OnClickListener() {` is an anonymous class and `this` here points to `anonymous` class not to your `Activity`

Comment: @desperateStudent i am glad that i could help , happy coding